# How to remove all previous devices in xp?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, usb-flash-drive

On our computers, we use daily dozens of different usb drives from our customers.

This is bad because the registry hive is becoming huge as windows is so "smart" to save them forever

I set `devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1` and i saw thousands of usb flash drives

There is a software that will automagically delete all previous devices?

Also this will solve a lot of problems with scanners and printers that will be seen as another device just because the user has plugged in another usb plug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/). From the website:

> "USBDeview is a small utility that
>   lists all USB devices that currently
>   connected to your computer, as well as
>   all USB devices that you previously
>   used.  For each USB device, exteneded
>   information is displayed: Device
>   name/description, device type, serial
>   number (for mass storage devices), the
>   date/time that device was added,
>   VendorID, ProductID, and more... 
>   USBDeview also allows you to uninstall
>   USB devices that you previously used,
>   and disconnect USB devices that are
>   currently connected to your computer. 
>   You can also use USBDeview on a remote
>   computer, as long as you login to that
>   computer with admin user."

The interface supports sorting and multiple select and remove. [Download here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usbdeview.zip)

Comment: wow this looks great!!! thank youuuuu!! NirSoft really rocks!

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has a command line utility called [DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/) which may do what you need.

List present and non-present USB devices:

```
devcon findall =usb
```

Remove all USB devices:

```
devcon remove @usb\*
```

Proceed with caution. You might need to do a `devcon rescan` or even a `devcon reboot` afterwards.

Comment: Kind of a distructive answer without a reboot command thrown in there - since the system will be left in an unusable state...

Comment: @Kara: For *USB*???

Comment: Unusable from the console, I should say, as the devices will not redetect.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

For storage volumes (USB drives) the Regisry Key is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\STORAGE\Volume
```

A little testing revealed that Non present devices have '??' in the key name.
One could write a simple program or script to cycle through the key names and delete the ones that have '??'.

Comment: \storage\ contains IDE/SATA drives, and yes, the non present devices have '??' in the name. But maybe the right one is \USBSTOR\?
In this case, the non present devices have a normal name...